# Fix html table height when gridview inside

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview inside an html table. I set row height to 30px, but when the content of gridview increases, the row height also expands.

Comment: Do u mean you want to set fix height of html table whatever is the height of gridview?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set fix height of html table whatever is the height of gridview, try wrapping your table inside `<div>` with `overflow:auto;`

```
<div style="height:100px; overflow:auto;">

.... Your table

...

</div>
```

Comment: i try it, didn't help. And the result is not what i want. i just want to fix the height of my table, but the gridview inside it can adjust according the rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a way to solve the problem, but it look a bit stupid: 
I put a 'height="30px"' in every 'td', then it work.
I try to put height in 'tr', it didn't work.
Please advice me for a better way. Thank you.

Comment: i just notice that this also not work when i run on microsoft edge!! anyone can let me know why?